# Putting a while loop into a for loop

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to simply TURN this into a for loop?

```
while ((something == false) && (s < string.length-1)){ }
```

Comment: I mean not physically put it in a for loop, but how can i turn it into a for loop.

Comment: Why do you want to turn it into a `for` loop? Looks fine, other than the extra parentheses.

Comment: Where is the difficulty? Why do you think there is no way?

Comment: `for (; (something == false) && (s < string.length-1); ) { }`

Comment: One of my coursework requirements is to have a for loop that does something like this is it possible?  most things i've tried makes me get stuck in an infinite loop :(

Comment: @p.s.w.g Isn't that just a glorified while loop? Putting the `check` condition in a for loop without `initialize` and `iterate`?

Comment: @BlueIce That was exactly the point I was trying to make.

Answer (score 2):

```
for( <x> ; (something == false) && (s < string.length-1) ; <y> ){
 //do whatever
}
```

put into x whatever you need to declare and into y whatever should increment everyloop, if anything. You can have nothing in there too.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=false;i<string.length-1;i++)
```

I am thinking that this will work

Comment: No it won't. It's not even valid JavaScript.